# Does xsd:choice require one or the other, or are both allowed too?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have two complex types and an element in an XML can take any of these two types. And sometimes, I know which one of these type the element can take. So accordingly I define in XSD.

```
<xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="one" type="onetype" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="two" type="twotype" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="three" type="country" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="oneattr" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="twoattr" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="B">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="four" type="fourtype" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="fourattr" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```

But sometimes i don't, so i have created another type like `AorB`.

```
<xs:complexType name="AorB">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="one" type="onetype" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="two" type="twotype" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="three" type="country" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="four" type="fourtype" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="oneattr" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="twoattr" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="fourattr" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
```

So my question is this:  **Of the two sequences inside `xsd:choice`, when the XML is validated, does it validate true if XML contains elements from both sequence or only one ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `xsd:choice` requires one or the other

> when the XML is validated, does it validate true if XML contains
>   elements from both sequence or only one ?

The default of `@minOccurs` on `xsd:choice` is `1`, which means one or the other, not both, of the children content models apply.  If you add `minOccurs="`*value*`"` for *value* greater than `1` or for *value* equal to `unbounded`, then multiple occurrences of its children are allowed.  Note, however, that the second occurrence might be a repeat of the child chosen from the first occurrence.

Comment: ok. how about above the case  xsd choice minoccurs=1 by default ?

Comment: The default of `xsd:choice/@minOccurs="1"` means one or the other, not both.